# A possible bug about ParametricPlot in version 13.3

Tags: plotting, bugs, regions

### example 1

```
ParametricPlot3D[{x, y, 0}, {x, y} ∈ MengerMesh[2, 2]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

### example 2

```
With[{regmem = RegionMember[MengerMesh[2, 2]]}, 
  ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
   RegionFunction -> 
    Function[{x, y}, regmem@{x, y}]]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

### example 3

```
ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 30, 
  RegionFunction -> 
   Function[{x, y}, {x, y} ∈ 
     MengerMesh[2, 2]]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

but

### example 4

```
ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {x, y} ∈ MengerMesh[2, 2]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

It take long time to get this picture(need `148`). When I test version 11.3, it only need `0.8`

```
$Version
(* 11.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 27, 2018) *)

ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {x, y} ∈ MengerMesh[2, 2]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

Comment: Can you be explicit? What do you regard as a bug here?

Comment: Could you use `Show[Region[MengerMesh[2, 2], Frame -> True]]` instead?

Comment: @ChrisK Since I want to transform a region, for example `ParametricPlot[{x - y^2/2, y - x^2/2}, {x, y} ∈ 
  MengerMesh[2, 2]]`, and at usually, `ParametricPlot` is faster then `TransformedRegion`.

Comment: @herbertfederer Thanks, I'm not familiar with the 2D version of `ParametricPlot`.

Comment: @ChrisK - the `Show` in your code doesn't contribute anything. `Region[MengerMesh[2, 2], Frame -> True]` produces the same result.

Comment: Cannot reproduce your example 4. On my ancient comp in 13.3.0 on Windows 10  it results in 8.4132 s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed in version 13.3.1

```
$Version
ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {x, y} ∈ 
   MengerMesh[2, 2]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

Comment: where did you get 13.3.1 from? I went to my portal at Wolfram and it is still says 13.3 latest. I went to the cloud and it says 13.3 there also. Was this even announced? When was it released?

Comment: @Nasser Some user can update to 13.3.1 now, maybe release soon  :)

Comment: I got an email about Wolfram Desktop 13.3.1. I have not received an email about Mathematica 13.3.1.

Answer (score 2):

Somebody has forgotten to set the plot point number

```
ParametricPlot[{x,y}, {x,y} ∈ MengerMesh[2, 2],
  PlotPoints -> 4] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

Comment: (+1)Thanks, since `PlotPoints->0` also work. It indicate that it is actually a bug.